# SQLite .NET performance, how to speed up things?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, sqlite, insert

On my system, ~86000 SQLite insertions took up to 20 minutes, means ~70 insertions per second. I have to do millions, how can I speed up it? Calling Open() and Close() on SQLiteConnection object for every line can slow down performance? Can transactions help?

Typical insertion method for a single line:

```cs
public int InsertResultItem(string runTag, int topicId,
    string documentNumber, int rank, double score)
{
    // Apre la connessione e imposta il comando
    connection.Open();

    command.CommandText = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Result "
    + "(RunTag, TopicId, DocumentNumber, Rank, Score) " +
    "VALUES (@RunTag, @TopicId, @DocumentNumber, @Rank, @Score)";

    // Imposta i parametri
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RunTag", runTag);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TopicId", topicId);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentNumber", documentNumber);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rank", rank);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", score);

    // Ottieni il risultato e chiudi la connessione
    int retval = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();

    return retval;
}
```

As you can see, insertions are very simple ones.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You definitely need a transaction. If you don't, SQLite starts its own transaction for every insert command so you're effectively doing 86000 transactions as is.

It looks you're also opening and closing the connection each time, along with resetting the CommandText each time. This is unnecessary and doubtless slowing you down, it'll go much faster if you:

- Open the connection once
- Build the command once , adding the parameters to it once.
- Start the transaction
- Loop through, changing the parameter values only before calling ExecuteNonQuery
- Commit the transaction.
- Close the connection.

I think you could reduce your 20 minutes down to just a few seconds this way.

Edit: this is what I mean:

```
public void InsertItems()
{
    SQLiteConnection connection  = new SQLiteConnection(SomeConnectionString);
    SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    SQLiteTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

    command.CommandText = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Result "
+ "(RunTag, TopicId, DocumentNumber, Rank, Score) " +
  "VALUES (@RunTag, @TopicId, @DocumentNumber, @Rank, @Score)";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RunTag", "");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TopicId", "");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentNumber", "");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rank", "");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", "");

    foreach ( /* item to loop through and add to db */ )
    {
        InsertResultItem(runTag, topicId, documentNumber, rank, score, command);
    }

    transaction.Commit();
    command.Dispose();
    connection.Dispose();
}

public int InsertResultItem(string runTag, int topicId, string documentNumber, int rank, double score, SQLiteCommand command)
{
    command.Parameters["@RunTag"].Value = runTag;
    command.Parameters["@TopicId"].Value = topicId;
    command.Parameters["@DocumentNumber"].Value = documentNumber;
    command.Parameters["@Rank"].Value = rank;
    command.Parameters["@Score"].Value = score;
    return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

It only uses one connection, one transaction and one command, so all you're changing is the parameter values each time.

Comment: I can't, simply because the loop is in another class... how about implementing IDisposable and committing the transaction on Dispose()?

Comment: I think the details of how you implement it are up to you really, just as long as you use just the one connection/transaction/command it'll be much faster than what you've got at present anyway.

Comment: I've been able to get a further 1/4 reduction in time by using this method with bigger prepared INSERT statement that inserts 10 rows at a time and has 10 times as many parameters. I assume it's faster because it's making fewer native interop calls.

Comment: My performance metrics:   Takes 19832.0 ms to insert 100 rows  without using transaction.

Takes 797.0 ms to insert 10000 rows  with transaction.

Looks transaction is the single one dominant factor.

Answer (score 3):

Use transactions. This should make things faster. Also I would recommend you the following pattern:

```
public int InsertResultItem(string runTag, int topicId,
    string documentNumber, int rank, double score)
{
    // Apre la connessione e imposta il comando
    using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(SomeConnectionString))
    using (var command = new connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var tx = connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            command.CommandText = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Result "
                + "(RunTag, TopicId, DocumentNumber, Rank, Score) " +
                "VALUES (@RunTag, @TopicId, @DocumentNumber, @Rank, @Score)";

            // Imposta i parametri
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RunTag", runTag);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TopicId", topicId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentNumber", documentNumber);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rank", rank);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", score);

            // Ottieni il risultato e chiudi la connessione
            var retval = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            tx.Commit();
            return retval;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As InsertResultItem seems like it would be called in a loop, this is still opening a new connection, starting a new transaction and making a new command for each insert though. The speed would just be the same as in the OP's code.

Comment: @miket2e, this is not opening a new connection, ADO.NET uses a connection pool. Also starting a new transaction is exactly what speeds things up.

Comment: It's creating one transaction for each insert though. SQLite does this  implicitly anyway (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) if you don't explicitly state it, that's what I mean by it being the same. It needs to be one transaction wrapped around all inserts to make a difference. I'm not sure if he's using ADO.NET or not, if he's using SQLite embedded in an application (without ADO.NET) it'd be quicker to connect just once too.

Comment: Yes, InsertResultItem  is called by a loop every time a new line is fetched. So it's useless to use transactions?

Comment: No it's not useless, a transaction will make it much faster. You just need to refactor your code a bit so you're only using one transaction, not thousands of them. Say, create the command first and then pass it as a parameter to InsertResultItem - don't recreate it each time.

Comment: @miket2e: I can open the connection and begin transaction in my facade "DataWrapper" class's constructor, but when should I call close connection and transaction?