# SQlite Part of C# Application takes too long

Tags: c#, performance, sqlite

I'm making an application using c# winforms and sqlite as my database.

It simply reads textfiles, transfers them to the database, parses them, then displays user output.

Problem: The SQlite part is extremely slow. It takes about 3 mins for it to run the code related to filling up the database !

I'm new to programming so I don't really know what could be the key issue. Aside from trying to optimize my code to contain only what's needed, are there any tools that can help with making applications faster, cleaning up background junk, etc?

Here's the slow part of the app:

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

          SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
          SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
          SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;


          sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=database.db;Version=3;");


          sqlite_conn.Open();

          // create a new SQL command:
          sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();


          sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'abc' (Seq text, Field text, Desc text, Len text, Dec text, Typ text, Percnt text, Pop text, Alzero text, MaxLen text );";


          sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          // **** SQLITE TRANSFER SECTION 1 - transfer values from list1 to table1 *****

          sqlite_cmd.CommandText = " DELETE FROM abc";
          sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO abc (Seq, Field, Desc, Len, Dec, Typ, Percnt, Pop, Alzero, MaxLen) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10)";
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", 6);  // dummy initial values 
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", 878); 
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", 56);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", 6);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", 546);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", 565);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", 568);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", 526);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", 586);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", 526);


          for (int i = 0; i < NumListValues; i += 10) // Filling SQlite table rows and columns with values from our list 
          {
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", list[i]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", list[i+1]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", list[i+2]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", list[i+3]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", list[i+4]);
              if (i > 490)
                  break; 
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", list[i+5]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", list[i+6]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", list[i+7]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", list[i+8]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", list[i+9]);
              sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          }

          //   **** SQLITE TRANSFER SECTION 2 - transfer values from list2 to 2nd table *****

          sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 't2' (YYMM text, MinDate text, MaxDate text, TotalTrans text, DebitTrans text, AMOUNTINDOCUMENTCURREN text );";

          sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          sqlite_cmd.CommandText = " DELETE FROM t2";
          sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO t2 (YYMM, MinDate, MaxDate, TotalTrans, DebitTrans, AMOUNTINDOCUMENTCURREN ) VALUES (@b1, @b2, @b3, @b4, @b5, @b6)";
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b1", 6);  // dummy initial values 
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b2", 878); 
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b3", 56);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b4", 6);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b5", 546);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b6", 565);

         for (int i = 0; i < NumList2Values; i+= 6) // Filling SQlite table rows and columns with values from list2
         {
             sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b1", list2[i]);
             sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b2", list2[i+1]);
             sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b3", list2[i+2]);
             sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b4", list2[i+3]);
             sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b5", list2[i+4]);
             sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b6", list2[i+5]);
             sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }



        // Create table to transfer values from list 3

       sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 't3' (YYWW text, MinDate text, MaxDate text, TotalTrans text, DebitTrans text, AMOUNTINDOCUMENTCURREN text );";

       sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       sqlite_cmd.CommandText = " DELETE FROM t3";
       sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO t3 (YYWW, MinDate, MaxDate, TotalTrans, DebitTrans, AMOUNTINDOCUMENTCURREN ) VALUES (@c1, @c2, @c3, @c4, @c5, @c6)";
       sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c1", 6);  // dummy initial values 
       sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c2", 878); 
       sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c3", 56);
       sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c4", 6);
       sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c5", 546);
       sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c6", 565);

       for (int i = 0; i < NumList3Values ; i+= 6) // Filling SQlite table rows and columns with values from list2
       {
           sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c1", list3[i]);
           sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c2", list3[i+1]);
           sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c3", list3[i+2]);
           sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c4", list3[i+3]);
           sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c5", list3[i+4]);
           sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c6", list3[i+5]);
           sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       }
   }
```

Comment: it would be much faster if you execute all inserts with one ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4356379/2366976) might be helpful

Comment: You probably don't need the dummy initial values parameters.

Comment: @AntonioBakula can you pls explain with code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things I notice.

-You're never clearing out the list of parameters before you move onto the next insert statement. I'd run 'sqlite_cmd.Parameters.Clear()' in between each query that you're using parameters.

-You're running a ton of insert statements, a few 'create table' statements, and a 'delete everything from table' statement. These could all be done in a single transaction to greatly speed things up.

To use transactions, at the beginning run this SQL query.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

And after you're done your inserts run this query.

```
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Also, if you're new to using SQLite, this link might come in handy that lists all the possible SQLite commands and information on what they do.

http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html

Comment: Thanks ! But how would I actually use these transactions with my code? 
Should I just put everysqlite command inside the begin and commit transaction

Comment: Just run Begin Transaction before you create your first table, and run the Commit Transaction after your last insert command in your example code. Technically every single single SQL command you run will create it's own transaction if you didn't say "Begin Transaction" first. That's why begin transaction saves time, your 200+ SQL insert commands only need to create a single transaction, rather than 200+ individual transactions for each query.

Comment: Just tried it, went from 3 mins to 3 seconds :D