# Not opening and closing the database connection is slower

Tags: c#, database, performance, sqlite, dataset

I am working with a SQLite database in C#. I have to insert a block of records to the database. My first version simply used the automaticly generated insert method. But that takes about a second to run, and that's too slow for the client. So I thought I could optimize this by opening and closing the connection programmaticly at the beginning and end of the block.

So I have something like this: (I changed the variable names)

```
        try
        {
            tableAdapter.openInsertCommandConnection();

            foreach (Data data in _data)
            {
                tableAdapter.InsertCommand(bytevalue, id1, id2);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            tableAdapter.closeInsertCommandConnection();
        }
```

And

```
    private ConnectionState previousInsertCommandConnectionState;

    public void openInsertCommandConnection()
    {
        previousInsertCommandConnectionState = Adapter.InsertCommand.Connection.State;
        if (((Adapter.InsertCommand.Connection.State & ConnectionState.Open) != ConnectionState.Open))
        {
            Adapter.InsertCommand.Connection.Open();
        }
    }

    public void closeInsertCommandConnection()
    {
        if (previousInsertCommandConnectionState == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            Adapter.InsertCommand.Connection.Close();
        }
    }

    public virtual int InsertCommand(byte[] value, long id1, long id2)
    {
        if ((value == null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        }
        else
        {
            Adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters[0].Value = value;
        }
        Adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters[1].Value = id1;
        Adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters[2].Value = id2;
        ConnectionState previousConnectionState = Adapter.InsertCommand.Connection.State;
        if ((Adapter.InsertCommand.Connection.State & ConnectionState.Open) != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            Adapter.InsertCommand.Connection.Open();
        }
        int returnValue = Adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return returnValue;
    }
```

To my big surprise the second approach is about 1,5 times slower then just using the automaticly generated insert statement from the dataset that looks like this:

```
public virtual int Insert(byte[] value, long id1, long id2) {
        if ((value == null)) {
            throw new global::System.ArgumentNullException("value");
        }
        else {
            this.Adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters[0].Value = ((byte[])(value));
        }
        this.Adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters[1].Value = ((long)(id1));
        this.Adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters[2].Value = ((long)(id2));
        global::System.Data.ConnectionState previousConnectionState = this.Adapter.InsertCommand.Connection.State;
        if (((this.Adapter.InsertCommand.Connection.State & global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) 
                    != global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)) {
            this.Adapter.InsertCommand.Connection.Open();
        }
        try {
            int returnValue = this.Adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return returnValue;
        }
        finally {
            if ((previousConnectionState == global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)) {
                this.Adapter.InsertCommand.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I really don't understand how this could be since opening and closing the connection is supposed to be the most time consuming task.

Any ideas are appriciated.

Comment: Every time you run your code you are putting more items into the database so results keep on getting slower and slow.  You can only compare execution time when the database has exactly the same number of items.

Comment: No, I overwrite my database every time so the amount of records should be similar (though indeed not exactly the same)

Comment: Well, in order to have an accurate test, your records *should* be the exact same...

Comment: Wrap a single transaction around all statements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite .NET performance, how to speed up things?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356363/sqlite-net-performance-how-to-speed-up-things)

Comment: It's not really a duplicate though. The next step is the same, but I'm more interested in why the performance is not what I expected.